# %matplotlib tk is not working at jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJL6r.png)

```
%matplotlib tk

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, 500)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x**2))
plt.show()
```

In the jupyter notebook, I wanted to open a plot in a new window,

so I applied `%matplotlib tk` but the plot did not appear.

I would be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be slow to load, Please try with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

x = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, 500)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x**2))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But, i want to open new window.. so ```inline``` is not what i want..